# How do I make a sh file for running my software automatically?

Tags: bash, shortcuts

I want to make a sh file on my desktop to run a software for example "kerio-kvc"

I made a sh file on my desktop with this content automatically

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start
```

But when I run it, the file needs password. So I did somethings else. But none of them worked.

I want to make a shortcut in my `Desktop` for execute a software without need for root password.

How I have to do this?

Comment: Why you want to do this? IMO kerio should start automatically at boot

Answer (score 0):

You need to give yourself the privilege to run that command without a password. See

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/visudo.8.html

There are plenty of examples in the first page.